# unrecognized arguments: --available-to-other-tenants --password Password@1212

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to create an application using the Azure App service.

However, it shows the above error: unrecognized arguments:

The command that I use is --> az ad app create --available-to-other-tenants --display-name "rrwebappbot" --password "Password@1212"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***For the command :*** `az ad app create`

The error says that the given argument " --available-to-other-tenants" shouldnt be used as argument  for the command. You should use valid arguments.

I followed the [Microsoft-Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-create),Plaese check the correct command as given below.

***Example:***

```
az ad app create --display-name rithwikapp
```

[image]

You can use other arguments that are mentioned in the Microsoft Document I provided.

Answer (score 0):

When [creating an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app), there are four different types

- Accounts in this organizational directory only
- Accounts in any organizational directory
- Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts
- Personal Microsoft accounts

From there, can see you want **Accounts in any organizational directory**.

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-create), it's possible to see the command should include the parameter `--sign-in-audience` set to `AzureADMultipleOrgs`

So, your command should be something like

```
az ad app create --display-name rrwebappbot --sign-in-audience AzureADMultipleOrgs
```